# Russian Roulette Alternative?

Tags: game-design

Does anyone know of an established variation on Russian Roulette using dice or cards that doesn't involve shooting yourself in the head and would be somewhat child friendly?

Thanks :)

Comment: The only thing we can really find similar is something like "spin the bottle" and if it landed on you, you'd be out.

Comment: I like to play Russian Roulette, but i don't point the gun at me, and i use all eight bullets.  And oh yeah i don't call it Russian Roulette

Comment: Its called Craps...

Comment: Is this question on topic? Technically, the game can be played around a table with cards and dice, but "Russian roulette" is really a different animal with a different context. And the user is new.

Comment: @Tom, Russian Roulette is such a brutally simple game that I can't imagine anyone couldn't work out how to non-violently replicate it with a six-sided dice or a deck of cards.  I took the "point" of the question to be games with props that recreate the gun-pointing tension and drama of RR.  Of course, I could be completely mistaken in this, as I notice my answer isn't getting any upvotes ;)

Comment: @Tom, Wait, why is a user being new a reason to close a question? Voted to reopen -- the answers below prove that this is a legitimate, on-topic question with interesting responses.

Comment: @warbaker: I'm actually new at closing questions myself (barely on the site for 3 months). It struck me as a "borderline" question. Given that the user was new, I voted to close, on the theory that new users are more likely to ask borderline questions. If someone with high rep had asked it, I might have let it pass. But new users tend to attract more scrutiny.

Comment: Seems like a stupid question to me, asked only with the intention of "see what happens".

Comment: Have you checked out the card game Exploding Kittens? According to their [website](https://www.explodingkittens.com/): "It is a highly-strategic, kitty-powered version of Russian Roulette." Also note that the site says the game is fine for ages 7 and up.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy chocolate Russian roulette sets, the guns has 7 chocolate bullets filled with liquid chocolate and 1 chocolate bullets filled with hot sauce, these can be great fun.

http://www.treasureislandsweets.co.uk/acatalog/chocolate_russian_roulette.html

heres a link to a set :)

Comment: Yum! For similar mostly-delicious results you could use jellybeans.

Answer (score 1):

Not *necessarily* exactly what you're looking for, but a fun game involving waving a lot of waving around brightly-coloured foam pistols is [Ca$h 'n' Gun$](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/19237/cash-n-guns).

If you follow the link to the image gallery (underneath the box image), you will see lots of people humorously shooting themselves in the head, Russian Roulette-style.  It's what gamers tend to do when they're playing a game with foam gun components, and there's no other honourable way out.

Not sure this would be *small*-child friendly, but it depends on the precociousness of your children, and certainly it seems like it would be fine for ages about 10 and up.